# href on an image doesn't work

Tags: html, image, href

I'm trying to make a page refresh, when user clicks an image.

I tried something like this:

```
<a href="no_serie.php"><img style="max-width:150px; margin-top: 1px;"
    src="bootstrap/img/ICOMS-LOGO.jpg">
</a>
```

But this doesn't work. When I click on the picture, nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Full Code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="no_serie.php">
        <img style="max-width:300px; margin-top: 1px;" src="bootstrap/img/ICOMS-LOGO.jpg">          
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="ajouter_produit.php">Ajouter un Produit</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_lot.php">Ajouter un Lot</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_distributeur.php">Ajouter un Distributeur</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_employe.php">Ajouter un Employé</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue? You want to reload the page or do you want to send the user to a specific page?

Comment: Your code is correct (except you didn't close your image tag). Unless you can reproduce your issue in a fiddle, I don't think we're going to be much help.

Comment: Is the path of "no_serie.php" correct? is it in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: Show more html please or create fiddle pls

Comment: "no_serie.php" is the file where the code is written. When i click on the picture, i want to refresh the actual page.

Comment: did you have any js code in your page ? please give it for help

Comment: @paistra : No js code or other. Only html,css,php and i use some bootstrap stuff. I post my full code.

Comment: If the link is just referring to the same page, why not use `href="#"`?

Comment: @jacelysh : Yes tried already and same result :/

Comment: You don't have to use a closing `</img>` for the image tag.

Comment: @jacelysh : I removed it, like before and same result :/

Comment: Try adding this to the `a`:  `display: inline-table`.
This may help the `img` wrap within the `a`

Comment: I add this in css file => ".a{
 display: inline-table;
}" and nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, I found. It was my mistake, I removed the 3th div class ( <div class="navbar-header">) and now it works perfectly ^^ Thank you all for your help even if you didn't fix it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `navvar-header`. It disable the click event maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use **"#"** tag instead of **no_serie.php** .

Comment: Like I said, I got the same result :/ Soo there is nothing wrong in the code ?

Comment: Yes you didnt close the img tag by using /

Comment: Some says I dont need to close that tag and other tell me I need to ... :/ ?

Comment: You have to close img tag using <img src="" alt="" /> for better practices .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code. It works perfectly. Try to use another browser if possible.

Try to disable some extensions if you have some. Some browser might detect that you are on the  same page name and will not reload it.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome with 4 "addBlocks" extensions. In IE, it look just horrible and still doens't work. And in FireFox, same that in google chrome ... :/

Comment: @Booba__2012 Can you try to use http://google.com and check if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the link in the href in your anchor tag and add a javascript to it. 
 And your done. Please check the code below.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a onclick="location.reload();" href="javascript:;">
        <img style="max-width:300px; margin-top: 1px;" src="bootstrap/img/ICOMS-LOGO.jpg">          
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="ajouter_produit.php">Ajouter un Produit</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_lot.php">Ajouter un Lot</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_distributeur.php">Ajouter un Distributeur</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajouter_employe.php">Ajouter un Employé</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your anchor tag with the following piece of code:

`<a href="javascript:history.go(0)"> 
    <img style="max-width:150px; margin-top: 1px;" src="bootstrap/img/ICOMS-LOGO.jpg"/> 
</a>`